# Topology, locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space. Is $E$ locally compact space? I'm looking for a counterexample to this assertion. If you know anything please let me know.

Comment: A normed space is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$: it is separable (Fouries series) but $\dim L^2(-\pi,\pi) = \infty$, so that it can't be locally compact.

Comment: Thanks. This is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ be the space of square summable sequences, which is a Banach space, 
and a separable one. (Norm: $\|(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\|=(\sum\lvert a_n\rvert^2)^{1/2}$.)

For example the set $D$ of sequences which vanish, after some term, with rational terms is dense and countable:
$$
D=\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}: a_n\in\mathbb Q\,\,\&\,\, a_n=0\,\,\text{for sufficiently large $n$}\}.
$$
Let now $\boldsymbol{e}_n$ be the sequence with all the terms equal to zero, except of the $n$th term which is equal to 1.

Then the sequence $\{\boldsymbol{e}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} \subset \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ does not have a convergent subsequence. In fact $F=\{\boldsymbol{e}_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ in bounded by 1, and each of its points is isolated, as $\|\boldsymbol{e}_m-\boldsymbol{e}_n\|=\sqrt{2}$. Thus it is bounded, closed, infinite and with open cover
$$
\{B(\boldsymbol{e}_n,1):n\in\mathbb N\},
$$
without any sub-cover.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting.